# WCAT gives error: "must specify at least one of the following parameters -run, -update, -terminate, -showclients or -setclients"

Tags: command-line, wcat

When running WCAT on my windows XP machine via the commandline I get the following error:

> error: must specify at least one of
>   the following parameters -run,
>   -update, -terminate, -showclients or -setclients

The command I try to run is:

```
wcat.wsf -terminate -run  -t scenario.wcat -f settings.ubr -s localhost -singleip -x
```

And is copied directly from the readme.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that in the readme, it's not really a hyphens.

If you look at the hex code, you see that the fake hyphen in the readme is 0x96, a hyphen is 0x2d

So go ahead and replace all the hyphens in the line with real ones. It will work after that.

Comment: Copy/paste is from the devil!!! 
I remembered to replace the CR/LF characters properly, but for some reason I missed the dashes. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The problem exists because of an error in the regex matching in the wcat.wsf file. For some reason the regex:

```
 var run_regular_expression = /[-\/]run$/;
```

Will not match the "-run" argument

Changing it to:

```
 var run_regular_expression = /[\-\/]run$/;
```

Does match the run argument.

Another option is to change to commandline call to:

```
wcat.wsf /terminate /run  -t scenario.wcat -f settings.ubr -s localhost -singleip -x
```

using slashes instead of hyphens